# sql count query for article_id & user_id

Tags: sql

I'm not sure how to write the right COUNT query, I know only the basics crud operations. This table refers to 'like' function where 'article_id' can be 'liked' from 'user_id'.  The query should COUNT how many user_id one article_id has. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Please provide a database tag.  And you show data -- is that sample data?  The results?  How is it related to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT how many user_id's for each article_id

```
select
     article_id, count(distinct user_id) as count_of
from mytable
group by
     article_id
```

Answer (score 0):

To query for a specific article:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE article_id = X;
```

In the example above, this would return 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE article_id = 4;
```